# I need answer to the question and seems a valid one, still its closed, How will I get answer from SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked the following question:

[What are custom events and synthetic events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122454/)

I don't mind if its downvoted or else, but at least an answer should be given. This is a confusing topic, and if I get answer, it will be very helpful. I know the code wasn't there, because it never needed to be.

There have been some questions without any code, or may seem vague at first, but they helped lot of people. Example:

[What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

I just need an answer, of a simple question asked, because I think this is the best community with knowledgeable persons, who might provide their inputs and let it have some answer, which will help someone who later comes searching for answer of this simple question.

Comment: So in terms of answer quality, what are you expecting from us that MDN isn't already providing for you?

Comment: Pl let me know here at least, what's wrong with this question! :-/ (I mean asking here about the question at SO). :-/ :-/

Comment: I mean, I am still not sure of -- `types of events`, Also, custom vs synthetic. Or, are `keydown` & `dblclick` are browser events or not? if Not, then which classification they come...

Comment: It's just way too broad. We are not a tutorial site. There are much more focused sites for these types of questions or for research such as the aforementioned MDN.

Comment: I think the question is reasonably focused. MDN doesn't look to be entirely clear, and having an answer to this on SO as well is just fine. OP isn't looking for a tutorial, but a description of a specific difference between a couple of programming concepts. If I were a SME I could easily imagine a good answer for this in no more than 1-2 paragraphs

Comment: @Paulie_D - This is the only platform I know from 6 years. I am sorry, but could you suggest an alternative or better one! I'll ask there ...

Comment: Did anyone bother looking for dupes? Because there's [Event vs CustomEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40794580/215552), [Capture all the events (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25695913/215552), both of which describe how events work in JavaScript and the DOM in varying levels of detail...

Comment: All this seems to suggest that you still think that you are entitled to receiving an answer to your question. That was never the case, regardless of who asked it and how they asked it.

Comment: @Deadpool ppl are telling you "this isn't appropriate for here". Answering "ok, but can you answer me?" is.... really disingenuous, and makes it look like you don't care for this "best community" at **all**, as long as *you* get what you need. This isn't a community.... anyway

Comment: @Deadpool no one say illegitimate question. We said inappropriate for stack. And your meta question **here** is discussed to raise if the closure was legitimate or not. We **care** about keeping stuff correct when it comes to stack. Meta discussions go to meta. Technical discussions don't. No one made fun of you..... so I don't see where you're coming with this. Take a breather. Calm down. You seem a bit too emotional for this here :/. Honestly.

Answer (score 20):

There's a reason that it's closed.  It's honestly *too* broad.

A question about what events are in JavaScript would probably be fine.  It'd be closed as a dupe since I'm certain it's been asked before, but that would be fine.

A question about what custom events are in JavaScript would probably be fine.  It too would probably be closed as a dupe, but by itself it's okay.

A question about what synthetic events are in JavaScript would probably be fine.  It might get closed as a dupe, but by itself it's fine.

A question about **all three at once** is, by definition, too broad.  You'd be better served by looking at a tutorial rather than compelling us to gen one up for you.

Comment: Yep, this helped thanks -- Just clarify -- This means there are `only two types of events in JS` -- `browser  & custom/synthetic`? -- I am correct or not, that will do .... Or is there any `3rd category`?

Comment: You don't seem like you're getting it, @Deadpool.  I'm not answering the question because I'm not pretending to be a subject matter expert in JavaScript.  I'm telling you *why* your question would be closed and what you might be able to do to rescue it.

Comment: Christ, I sure hope some big wig in Stack Exchange sees this post.  This is what the community has been warning them about for decades and it's starting to boil my blood.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Mine one `boiled a billion times, every time when I expected some help or answer at SO`, & it was brutally downvoted -- again & again & again! Now, I just come here, expecting that's normal ... because its not the one, it used to be `years ago`. So, its okay :)

Comment: @Deadpool Please stop using code formatting for text that is not code. It is very distracting and makes it look like you're randomly pressing the tick mark key on your keyboard...